# Django time zone issue in my project dash board

Tags: python, django

I can't get the today_entries,week_entries and month_entries in the following code :

```
class DashBoardView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        # Count the number of users
        total_users = User.objects.count()
        total_workers = User.objects.filter(role='worker').count()

        total_credits = Decimal(0.00)
        total_debits = Decimal(0.00)
        wallet_entries = AdminWallet.objects.all()

        print("wallet entries",wallet_entries)

        today = timezone.now()
        print("today",today)
        start_of_week = today - timezone.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
        print("start_of_week",start_of_week)
        start_of_month = today.replace(day=1)
        print("start of the month",start_of_month)
        start_of_year = today.replace(month=1, day=1)
        print("start of the year",start_of_year)

        for entry in wallet_entries:
            total_credits += entry.credit
            total_debits += entry.debit

        total_balance = total_credits - total_debits
        print("total balance",total_balance)



        week_entries = wallet_entries.filter(created_at__gte=start_of_week)
        print("week entries",week_entries)
        month_entries = wallet_entries.filter(created_at__gte=start_of_month)
        print("month entries",month_entries)
        year_entries = wallet_entries.filter(created_at__gte=start_of_year)
        print("year entries",year_entries)

        total_revenue_week = sum(entry.credit for entry in week_entries) - sum(entry.debit for entry in week_entries)
        total_revenue_month = sum(entry.credit for entry in month_entries) - sum(entry.debit for entry in month_entries)
        total_revenue_year = sum(entry.credit for entry in year_entries) - sum(entry.debit for entry in year_entries)
        
        Pending_Bookings = Appointment.objects.filter(status='Pending').count()
        Accepted_Bookings = Appointment.objects.filter(status='Accepted').count()
        Cancelled_Bookings = Appointment.objects.filter(status='Cancelled').count()
        Rejected_Bookings = Appointment.objects.filter(status='Rejected').count()

        today_entries = wallet_entries.filter(created_at__date=today)
        print("today entries",today_entries)
        total_revenue_today = sum(entry.credit - entry.debit for entry in today_entries)
        seven_days_ago = today - timezone.timedelta(days=7)
        daily_Bookings_data = []
        daily_revenue_data = []

        for i in range(7):
            day_start = seven_days_ago + timezone.timedelta(days=i)
            day_end = day_start + timezone.timedelta(days=1)

        Appointments_on_day = Appointment.objects.filter(date1__gte=day_start, date1__lt=day_end).count()


        revenue_on_day = wallet_entries.filter(created_at__date=day_start).aggregate(
                total_credit=Sum('credit'),
                total_debit=Sum('debit')
        )
        print("revenue on day",revenue_on_day)
        if revenue_on_day['total_credit'] is not None and revenue_on_day['total_debit'] is not None:
            revenue_on_day = revenue_on_day['total_credit'] - revenue_on_day['total_debit']
        else:
            revenue_on_day = 0

        daily_Bookings_data.append(Appointments_on_day)
        daily_revenue_data.append(revenue_on_day)

        response_data = {
            "total_users": total_users,
            "total_workers": total_workers,
            "total_balance": total_balance,
            "total_revenue_week": total_revenue_week,
            "total_revenue_month": total_revenue_month,
            "total_revenue_year": total_revenue_year,
            "pending_bookings": Pending_Bookings,
            "accepted_bookings": Accepted_Bookings,
            "cancelled_bookings": Cancelled_Bookings,
            "rejected_bookings": Rejected_Bookings,
            "total_revenue_today": total_revenue_today,
            "daily_Bookings_data":daily_Bookings_data,
            "daily_revenue_data":daily_revenue_data
        }

        return Response(response_data)
```

Terminal shows like in below:

```
wallet entries <QuerySet [<AdminWallet: raya's Admin Wallet>]>
today 2023-12-13 16:28:59.854552+00:00
start_of_week 2023-12-11 16:28:59.854552+00:00
start of the month 2023-12-01 16:28:59.854552+00:00
start of the year 2023-01-01 16:28:59.854552+00:00
total balance 7900.00
week entries <QuerySet []>
month entries <QuerySet []>
year entries <QuerySet [<AdminWallet: raya's Admin Wallet>]>
today entries <QuerySet []>
revenue on day {'total_credit': None, 'total_debit': None}
HTTP GET /dashboard/ 200 [0.19, 127.0.0.1:62777]
```

in this you can see the year entries are getting but the problems in month and week ,how i solve it please give me appropriate solution for it ?

Comment: What is `created_at` for `<AdminWallet: raya's Admin Wallet>` in the above example? If it's earlier than this month, everything looks good.

Comment: created_at is a field of the <AdminWallet: raya's Admin Wallet> which shows the date and time of the object created.

Comment: We would like to know the value of this object.